# Data Is Missing On Figure Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, ode, differential-equations

I have a question - why is the part of data missing on the figure? Please help me, I am stuck and have no idea =(

Here is the code for ode:

```
function xDot = parallelDegreesW4(t,x,~,w_af,g_af,gcurr)
xDot  = [x(2); ... %//= theta'

    sin(x(1)) * cos(x(1)) * ((x(4))^2) + ...
    (w_af^2) * ((sin(x(1)))^3 * cos(x(1)) * (cos(x(3)))^4 + (sin(x(1)))^3 * cos(x(1)) * (sin(x(3)))^4 - (cos(x(1)))^3 * sin(x(1))  ) + ...
    - 2 * g_af * x(2) + ...
    + 2 * gcurr * sin(x(1)) * cos(x(1)) * sin(x(3)) * cos(x(3)); ...

    x(4); ... %//= phi'

    - x(2) * x(4) * cot(x(1)) + ...
    (w_af^2) * (sin(x(1)))^2 * cos(x(3)) * sin(x(3)) *(-(cos(x(3)))^2 + (sin(x(3)))^2) + ...
    - 2 * g_af * x(4) + ...
    + gcurr * ((cos(x(3)))^2 - (sin(x(3)))^2)];
```

Here is the code I run:

```
function f = ps(phi_vel,gcurr)
    w_af = 0.1;
    g_af = 0.01;
    %initial positions
    initial_theta = pi/2;
    initial_phi = (3*pi/4+pi/2)/2;
    %initial velocities
    initial_velocity_theta = 0;
    initial_velocity_phi = phi_vel;
    %finaly x0
    x0 = [initial_theta,initial_velocity_theta,initial_phi,initial_velocity_phi];

    time = 1000;
    tspan = 0:0.01:time;
    options = odeset('RelTol',1e-8,'AbsTol',[1e-8 1e-8 1e-8 1e-8]);

    [t,x]=ode45('parallelDegreesW4',tspan,x0, options,w_af, g_af, gcurr);
    xx1 = x(:,1);%theta
    xx2 = x(:,3);%phi
    xx3 = x(:,2);%V_theta
    xx4 = x(:,4);%V_phi
    %

    %
    %%
    ini_1=xx1(1);
    ini_2=xx2(1);
    ini_3=xx3(1);
    ini_4=xx4(1);
    last_1 = xx1(length(xx1)-1);
    last_2 = xx2(length(xx2)-1);
    last_3 = xx3(length(xx3)-1);
    last_4 = xx4(length(xx4)-1);


    figure(1)
  plot(initial_phi,initial_velocity_phi,'ok','MarkerSize',5,'MarkerFaceColor','g');
        hold on;
        plot(last_3,last_4,'ok','MarkerSize',5,'MarkerFaceColor', 'r');
        hold on;
        plot(xx3,xx4,'--','LineWidth' ,4);
        hold on;
```

After that I get such picture. 
[image]
(green means - start, red - finish of the movement of variable phi in the phase space)

So my question is, where is all the data that must show the movement from green to red?
This is weird, because, there is actually a dynamics, here below I have included picture where my variable phi depends on time.
Thank you for helping me!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're plotting theta and phi on V-theta and V_phi axes - too many initial conditions, which means the axes chosen by matlab to display theta_0 and phi_0 are zoomed out too far to display the line plot.

Try simply commenting out the first plot command

```
%plot(initial_phi,initial_velocity_phi,'ok','MarkerSize',5,'MarkerFaceColor','g');
```

to get a graph of `V_phi` vs `V_theta` and running `ps(2,1)` to get a phase space of the velocities.  Or try commenting out everything after `figure(1)` and replacing it with

```
    plot(t,xx2,'--','LineWidth' ,4);
```

and running `ps(.2,.3)` to get soemthing like the example you're seeking.
Also for testing purposes to make it run faster I increased the error bounds to

```
options = odeset('RelTol',1e-3,'AbsTol',[1e-3 1e-3 1e-3 1e-3]);
```

and reduced `time` to `time = 400; %1000;` and `tspan` to `tspan = 0:0.05:time;  %0:0.01:time;`
- if you can already guess the solution you're looking for decays exponentially, there's little to be learned by continuing to solve it over a very large time domain, especially with a fixed time step ODE solver.  Also I needed to remove the `~`  in the function header like so `function xDot = parallelDegreesW4(t,x,w_af,g_af,gcurr)` to get it to work in octave.

Comment: You are right! I had an suspicion that due to scales I have a problem, nevertheless did not check it myself. Thank you JamesP!